# Error accessing .HasValue on nullable DateTime variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, msbuild, nullable

I'm getting the following error, when accessing the .HasValue property of a nullable `DateTime?` variable (when it doesn't have a value).

It works fine on my development machine (Win 10, VS 2017), but after being built by a TFS v15.117 build definition (set to use VS  2017 version), and published to a client's server (Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard), the following error is thrown:

> [NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not
>   set.]    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Container..ctor(Object
>   Instance) +1479606
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) +250

Why would `myDateTimeVar.HasValue` work on one system, but fail like this on another?

EDIT:

`Dim testDate1 As DateTime? = Nothing`
`Dim testDate2 As DateTime? = DateTime.Now`
`Dim testDate3 As DateTime? = DateTime.MinValue`
`Dim testDate4 As DateTime?`
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate1.HasValue) 'False`
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate2.HasValue) 'True`
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate3.HasValue) 'True`
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate4.HasValue) 'False`

*[Based around discussion in comments on J's answer]* This code runs perfectly in the project locally. Does Option Strict get applied differently in different Configurations / Environments do you think? (Although the TFS Build Def was set to use Debug)

Comment: Where's the code?  Why are you using late-binding in the first place?  You should set `Option Strict On` for this project and for every other project and leave it `On` unless you specifically need late-binding. Even if you do need it, you should create partial classes containing the minimum possible code that uses late-binding and turn `Option Strict Off` just for those files.

Comment: Heh, you've spotted the dirty secret at the heart of the sprawling legacy system I'm working on, `Option Strict` is very much `Off` I hadn't thought about turning it on, on a class by class basis, where possible. I'll give that a go. I'll put a code sample up too in a sec.

Comment: All the examples you posted are early-bound. Try assigning all those `DateTime?` variables to `Object` variable and get `HasValue` on those, as I demonstrated in my answer.  I'll wager that you'll see the same behaviour I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this code and saw the same behaviour you describe:

```vb
Option Strict Off

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim nullableDate As Date? = Nothing
        Dim boxedNullableDate As Object = nullableDate

        Console.WriteLine(boxedNullableDate.HasValue)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

The reason for the exception would be that boxing a `Date?` that has no value gives you an `Object` reference that is `Nothing` and trying to access any member of `Nothing` throws a `NullReferenceException`.

That basically means that late-binding with nullable value types is just not going to work.

EDIT:

Interestingly, I just changed the code to this:

```vb
Option Strict Off

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim nullableDate As Date? = Date.Now
        Dim boxedNullableDate As Object = nullableDate

        Console.WriteLine(boxedNullableDate.HasValue)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

and now I get a `MissingMemberException` with the message:

> Public member 'HasValue' on type 'Date' not found.

It seems like boxing a nullable value type doesn't retain the knowledge that the original variable was nullable.  The debugger just recognises the `Object` variable as `Object` alone if it's `Nothing`, otherwise `Object {Date}`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much J, it's great to get it know why this is happening, and to be able to stop worrying that it was my TFS build settings. Why would it work differently on my dev machine as opposed to a production server though?

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer. Based on that, I'm not sure how getting `HasValue` using late-binding could ever work. Maybe when it was working you were actually getting `HasValue` on a `Date?` variable and not on an `Object` reference.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I have seen that second error message at times too. It's weird, as I'm really sure that the nullable DateTime has worked correctly locally. I might have a play with adding my own .HasValue extension method, with a try catch, or just start initialising things with MinDate. Sigh. Oh to work on a system not based on someone's 10 year old code written in a hurry....

Comment: `Dim testDate1 As DateTime? = Nothing`  `Dim testDate2 As DateTime? = DateTime.Now`  
`Dim testDate3 As DateTime? = DateTime.MinValue`  
`Dim testDate4 As DateTime?`  
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate1.HasValue) 'False`  
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate2.HasValue) 'True`  
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate3.HasValue) 'True`  
`Debug.WriteLine(testDate4.HasValue) 'False`  

This code runs perfectly in the project locally. Does Option Strict get applied differently in different Config'ns / Env's do you think? (Although the TFS Build Def was set to use Debug)

Comment: I've just added some code using nullable dates to the question, that works perfectly inside the same project, on my dev machine. (Although, no worries if this is all getting a bit off track, and you've got better things to do than do my work for me! Your answer and comments have put me on track to getting something working I'm sure. Thanks again.)

Comment: None of those examples are using late-binding though. In every case, the variable you're getting `HasValue` on is type `DateTime?`. Late-binding only occurs when you assign one of those variable to an `Object` variable and then try to get `HasValue` on that.  The stack trace information you posted in your question definitely indicates that late-binding is being used.  It seems like there might be a small number of situations - possibly only one - where you are getting HasValue on an `Object` reference rather than a `DateTime?` value.

Comment: Ah, of course, duh! That's got the final penny to drop now. Many, many thanks. I'll now go and read an article about late-binding, and have a think about the best work around for this, given the constraints of our current system.

Comment: @Ted, see: [Nullable<T> Structure - Boxing and Unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)